# RabbitMQ Clustering node failure

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ cluster (without HA) setup with the nodes in multiple instances. From the documentation, what I understood is, in cluster mode, the queues are not mirrored and it is owned by the node where it is declared.

So, now the question is, what will happen when the node which owns the queue goes down? Correct me if I'm wrong, since the queues are not mirrored, the client applications will throw up for missing queues.

Should we write our logic to figure out if the node goes down, the queues have to be re declared and in this case, what will happen to the messages?

Comment: if node own the queue dead,the queue dead,the message dead.You could check existence and then decide to declare or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, now the question is, what will happen when the node which owns the queue goes down?

From the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html):

> When RabbitMQ quits or crashes it will forget the queues and messages unless you tell it not to. Two things are required to make sure that messages aren't lost: we need to mark both the queue and messages as durable.

next question:

> Should we write our logic to figure out if the node goes down, the queues have to be re declared and in this case, what will happen to the messages?

Yes, its a good idea to re-declare your queues.

In case when your node is going down, all consumers connected to it will be disconnected. Every time consumer connects, it should assume it's queue does not exist and so, it needs to fire `declare queue` request as first request when its connected.

If consumer sends `declare queue` request and queue `does exist` then:

- `declare queue` won't affect queue's
  messages in any way. If messages were persisted, they continue to be
  in the queue.
- Under normal circumstances (if you don't change the queue's
  properties) no errors will be thrown